# Redirecting POST to external URL in Codeigniter sometimes gets stuck

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-2, payment-gateway

I have a payment API made using CodeIgniter.

My clients posts data like `orderid, amount` to the API (a CodeIgniter controller) and I authenticate the request. If it's okay, I load a payment page using `$this->load->view`.

After filling the form, the form data is posted to another controller and from there, using models I fetch the relevant data I need to save, like the transaction ID etc generated in the database, and submit the card details to my processor who process the transaction.

Now my issue is, from the last controller when I post my data to the processor, it's getting stuck,but sometimes it works!

I'm using cURL GET to pass the data which is encrypted. I tried header location, I tried redirect, I tried hidden form post. But all are in vain.

I don't know what is the problem. It works sometimes, sometimes it gets stuck on the redirection to external URL.

What can be the issue? Before I was using CodeIgniter I used raw PHP, in which this worked fine. But this MVC model is creating problem. Has anyone had an issue like this?

Code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Triggerpay extends CI_Controller
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();

                $this->load->model('check_mid');
        }
        public function pay()
        {
                        $remoteIP='23.24.35.5';
                        $merchantid="ESS000";
                        $Password="zyqqby";
                        $currencyCode='356';
                        $tokenex_cipherText = $this->input->post('tokenex_cipherText');
                        $app_data['app_used'] = $appused = $this->input->post('app');
                        $trans_data['token_id'] = $token = $this->genToken($tokenex_cipherText);
                        $expiryMonth = $this->input->post('expiry_month');
                        $expiryYear = $this->input->post('expiry_year');
                        $securityCode = $this->input->post('cvv');
                        $trans_data['cardHolderName'] =$cardHolderName= $this->input->post('name_on_card');
                        $trans_data['trans_amount'] = $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
                        $trans_data['cardProvider'] = $cardProvider = $this->input->post('ccType');
                        $cardType = $this->input->post('cardType');
                        $trans_data['mobileNo'] = $mobileNo = $this->input->post('mobileNo');
                        $trans_data['cust_Email'] = $Email = $this->input->post('email');
                        $app_data['app_id'] = $apikey = $this->input->post('ak');
                        $app_data['orderID'] = $orderID = $this->input->post('orderID');
                        $app_data['trans_refNo'] = $trans_data['trans_refNo'] = $customerReferenceNo = $this->check_mid->get_new_ref_no();
                        //echo "data is ".$app_data['app_used'];
                        if($app_data['app_used'] == 'Checkout')
                                $app_data['merchant_id'] = $trans_data['merchant_id'] = $mer_id = $this->check_mid->get_user_by_apikey($apikey);
                        else if($app_data['app_used'] == 'Buttn')
                                $app_data['merchant_id'] = $trans_data['merchant_id'] = $mer_id = $this->check_mid->get_user_by_button_id($apikey);
                        else if($app_data['app_used'] == 'Invoiz')
                                $app_data['merchant_id'] = $trans_data['merchant_id'] = $mer_id = $this->check_mid->get_user_by_inv_no($apikey);

                        if($cardType=='radio1')
                                {
                                        $cardType='CC';
                                }
                        if($cardType=='radio2')
                                {
                                        $cardType='DB';
                                }              
                        if($cardProvider=='visa_electron')
                                {
                                        $cardProvider='SBIME';
                                }
                        if($cardProvider=='mastercard')
                                {
                                        $cardProvider='MC';
                                }
                        if($cardProvider=='maestro')
                                {
                                        $cardProvider='MAEST';
                                }
                        if($cardProvider=='visa')
                                {
                                        $cardProvider=='VISA';
                                }
                                $trans_data['trans_type'] = $cardType;
                                $cardProvider=strtoupper($cardProvider);
                                $name=$cardHolderName;
                                $this->check_mid->set_trans_data($trans_data, $app_data);
                                $checksum = $merchantid."|".$amount."|".$customerReferenceNo;  
                                $checksum = hash('sha256', $checksum); 
                                $data='tokenNo='.$token.'&securityCode='.$securityCode.'&cardExpiryMonth='.$expiryMonth.'&cardExpiryYear='.$expiryYear.'&cardHolderName='.$cardHolderName.'&transactionAmount='.$amount.'&paymentMode='.$cardType.'&currencyCode='.$currencyCode.'&customerReferenceNo='.$customerReferenceNo.'&cardProvider='.$cardProvider.'&name='.$name.'&mobileNo='.$mobileNo.'&email='.$Email.'&password='.$Password.'&amount='.$amount.'&remoteIP='.$remoteIP.'&checkSum='.$checksum;           
                                $encryption_key = "CE51E07D964";
                                $desEncryptedData = $this->encryptText_3des($data, $encryption_key);
                                $desEncryptedData = urlencode($desEncryptedData);
                                $external['url'] = 'https://payment.edfgffdgfg.com/PGCCDCToken/TokenPayment.jsp?merchantId='.$merchantid.'&data='.$desEncryptedData;
                                //$this->load->view('process',$external);
                                $curl = curl_init();
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

                                $auth = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: You will probably need to provide some code.

Comment: This is the controller from where data is posted to process    http://pastebin.com/sFfXZWKy    It is getting stuck after the curl execution

Comment: Well have you checked for cURL errors?